# calling static method with static class variable as class name in php

Tags: php, class, oop, static

I know you can call static methods using variable as class name like so:

```
$className = "Foo";  
$className::Bar(); //works
```

But when i'm trying to use static property as variable like this:

```
self::$className = "Foo";
self::$className::Bar();  //doesn't
```

it gives me the following parse error on line where i'm trying to call the method:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
```

So how can i call that method using static property and is that even possible with syntax somewhat similar to what i described(w/o `call_user_func` and creating local variable that stores `self::$className`)?

Comment: Have you tried using [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)?

Comment: @Svengali if possible i wan't to call that method like i described

Comment: This syntax is wrong. The word ```self``` refers to the class name of the current class scope. So basically, what you are trying to say is "call a method (```Bar()```) from class (```$className```) of the current class ```self```". It doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: @Avalanche well, yes. I don't see what's wrong here, current class `self` has property `$className` and i'm trying to call a method from class which name is equal to `$className` value.

Comment: @DanilSolodunov what if init class and then call method? Will it solve your question? Example: `(new self::$className)->Bar();`

Comment: @VladimirGilevich it will not since i need to call static method

Comment: You have two quick options: either use a local variable as suggested in @rlanvin's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32137669/4265352) or use PHP 7. The more elaborate (and probably the correct) option is to extract the static methods and properties into a separate class and use inheritance and polymorphism to implement the functionality you need. You'll discover that your problem will vanish together with the line of code that generated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that:

```
$tmp = self::$className;
$tmp::Bar();
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments it seems your problem is more about OOP design than it is about syntax. Furthermore, you keep adding new restrictions every time a solution is given, which makes it difficult to provide a relevant answer.

Anyway, I'll try to summarize your options. The syntax you want does not exist (at the moment, anyway), so you have to work around it one way or another. Yes, this is annoying, and yes this means that you will have to make concessions. But that's how it is.

Here are your options so far:

- Use `call_user_func` or `forward_static_call` or similar.
- Use a temporary local variable. Possibly wrap that into a method if it's **really** bothering you (e.g. `static function call($method) { $tmp = self::$classname; return $tmp::$method(); }` and then use `self::call('bar');`)
- Refactor your object design using instances instead of static methods so that you don't need to do that anymore.
- Use some other terribly ugly and dangerous hack (e.g. `eval(self::$classname.'::bar();');` and hope it won't come bite you in the butt.

Comment: that's pretty obvious and not what i want

Comment: how is it not what you want?

Comment: i need to use `self` class property and not the local variable

Comment: Yeah but what you want is an invalid syntax, it's not possible. So you have to work around it with an extra variable (or use call_user_func, but you don't want that either so...)

Comment: i understand that what i wrote is an invalid syntax, that's why i asked the question in the first place, i need something similar and was wondering if there's a way to do this without call_user_func and creating local variable

Comment: i would have to create it in every single method of class then

Comment: @DanilSolodunov I edited my answer with more details. As far as I know, the perfect answer you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: okay thanks for help, i'll mark your answer as correct since you've described all posible options pretty well